# Error when importing vector layer into GRASS

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, vector

I am trying to import a vector layer into GRASS, but I keep receiving the same error.  The values in the vector layer are important because I would like to use them to create a heatmap.  What could I be doing wrong?

Yesterday I managed to import the layer into GRASS, but it had discarded all the values.

[image: The error message received when trying to import a vector layer into GRASS]

Comment: Perhaps there is some error with QGIS?  I know that there are some features that I have problems with in GRASS since installing certain plugins.  Uninstalling and reinstalling QGIS did not help, but I did manage to repair some of the damage by manually replacing missing files.  Is there another way to 'repair' QGIS?

Comment: have you tried running <code>v.in.ogr</code> in GRASS?

Comment: Tried this method, it just results in an error as well.

Comment: Have you checked the layer's geometry validity? I had the same trouble recently and that did the trick for me.

Comment: Sorry, still rather new to all of this.  How do I check the layer's geometry validity?

Comment: Which GRASS version do you use there? Secondly, is there a white space in the installation path? We tried to catch all problems on Windows related to that but who knows. Are you on Windows?

Comment: I'm using QGIS 1.8.0 (GRASS 6.4.2), and yes, I'm using Windows.  There seem to have been some files damaged or moved when I installed some new plugins a while back.  Even though I manually replaced some of the files, QGIS has never been the same again and I'm wondering whether that doesn't have something to do with it?  NVIZ for example would not run until I had replaced a couple of the missing files.  Found another issue the other day, and finally just gave up on repairing it.

Comment: You can check the validity using Vector -> Geometry Tools -> Check Geometry Validity.

Comment: Thank you, checked the layer's geometry validity and it found no errors.

Comment: After many fruitless attempts, I finally changed the columns around in the spreadsheet and voila!  It worked.  Thanks for all the help offered.

Comment: Please post the latter as new answer to make the solution more obvious (so, in the end it appeared to be a data problem). Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many fruitless attempts, I finally changed the columns around in the spreadsheet and voila! It worked. Thanks for all the help offered.